# How to get tamed wolves to not attack other players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft with my friend. I like having tamed wolves, but it's so easy to accidentally have them go into murder-mode on my teammate. Is there any way to get them to never become hostile towards other players? Maybe some kind of server command?

Answer (score 10):

Wolves will not attack other players if the player and the wolf owner are on the same team.

To create a team:

```
/scoreboard teams add Friendly
```

To add players to it:

```
/scoreboard teams join Friendly @a
```

Comment: In 1.13.1 when I attempt to use the `/scoreboard` command only `players` and `objectives` are available there is no `teams` option.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/team add Friendly` and `/team join Friendly @a`

Answer (score 0):

Tamed wolves will never attack fellow players, unless your fellow players attack them first.

In short, tell your teammate to stop punching your dogs, and you'll be fine.

Comment: In a local lan game, one of the players (call him Fred) accidentally hit another player (call her Sally) with a pickaxe while mining. A while later, back at the house, Sally's dog starts attacking Fred. They didn't know what to do, so Sally ended up having to kill her own dog. Very sad :-(

Answer (score -1):

This problem is common among players in multiplayer. To stop your wolf from killing your friend you have to kill your friend yourself ;) just kidding.
Your friend should sprint and run 50 blocks away from the wolf, or jump into lava/water (don't ever choose lava).
Note - never punch or hurt the wolf in reply during the activity.

Answer (score -2):

I have had this problem before, and I even went onto the wiki. As far as I'm aware as long as your friend doesn't hit you around your tamed wolves they will be friendly around them. If they are in the sitting position as most people are aware they will stay where you left them and will not engage in combat against anything that attacks you as long as you are far enough away from the tamed wolf. Hope this helps.